# How hide in the view shipping in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

[image: ipping]

I want hide the text SHIPPING, in Magento v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please override your file

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js

to

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js

**Change Below Function Your Theme**

```
getShippingMethodTitle: function () {
        var shippingMethod,
            shippingMethodTitle = '';

        if (!this.isCalculated()) {
            return '';
        }
        shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();

        if (typeof shippingMethod['method_title'] !== 'undefined') {
            shippingMethodTitle = shippingMethod['method_title'];
        }

        return shippingMethod ? shippingMethodTitle : '';
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide any shipping details from
checkout/cart/shipping.phtml file either from theme or from vendor

You can also override this file using any custom module or theme module .
I hope this will help you ...
Happy Coding !!!